# Firefox extension do somethig when mouse right click is press

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, mouseevent, browser-extension

I created a context menu item and want to do this before the context menu appear.

```
function mousePress() {
    if (isNullOrWhitespace(info.selectionText)) {
        browser.menus.update("translate-page", { title: "Translate Page" });
    } else {
        browser.menus.update("translate-page", { title: "Translate Text" });
    }
}
```

I try with this but i really don't know how to do it.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/mousedown_event
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/buttons

Edit: Complete code
https://github.com/Hellboy00000/Page-Translator-3

Edit 2: I wanted to add this before publishing the extension but decide to publish the extension a few days ago. Here is the link:
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/page-translator-3/

Easy explanation of what i want:
If text selected
Context Menu text say "Translate Text"
else (no text selected)
Context Menu text say "Translate Page"

Comment: Try it with the [`contextmenu event`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/contextmenu_event) and don't forget to use [`event.preventDefault()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault), if you want to prevent the default context menu to be shown.

Comment: I don't want to prevent Default context menu. I want to do this in JavaScript inside the background.js. I try but always tell me context menu is undefined. Looks like this examples are more for HTML.

Comment: Can you add the Javascript code, where you have tried it with the contextmenu event, in your question?

Comment: This is the first time i work with JavaScript. I am going to upload all the extension to GitHub tomorrow and share the link here.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Add the link for the code.

Comment: Add Firefox link to install extension and a easy explanation.